# How to add a line of text to the first and last row of a flat file using Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, automation, databricks

I have some flat files that I need to add a "header" and "footer" to. The issue is that the header and footer is used for processing only and thus they do not have the same number of columns as the actual data.

What I'm currently doing is adding the header and footer manually to the file by opening it up, but I would like to automate this step. [image: Example Data of what I am talking about]

As you can see in the example above, the header and footer have more columns than the actual data. If I try and append the header and footer to the Pandas dataframe before outputting the file, it will create new columns for the data with null values, which I do not want.

All suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

Just write header and footer separately using standard Python.

```
df = <...>
with f as open("out.txt", "w"):
  f.write("ORGHEADER|01|...\n")
  df.to_csv(f, header=False, index=False)
  f.write("ORGFOOTER|01|...")
```